# Text on SVG circle

Tags: html, svg, highcharts

I am trying to show SVG color with multiple color and text on it like shown in this pic

[image: chart]

Here is the JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3cx6mLy0/.

I am able to create the color but text is not coming

```
series: [{
        name: 'Move',
        data: [{
            color:  '#FF0000',
            radius: '112%',
            innerRadius: '65%',
            y: 60
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Exercise',
        data: [{
            color: 'green',
            radius: '112%',
            innerRadius: '65%',
            y: 20
        }]
    }]
});
```

Can you please tell me what exactly need to do to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the wanted result by using `dataLabels` and `legend` properties:

```
  plotOptions: {
      solidgauge: {
          ...,
          dataLabels: {
              formatter: function() {
                  var series = this.series.chart.series,
                      index = this.series.index;

                  if (index !== series.length - 1) {
                      return (this.y - series[index + 1].points[0].y) + '%'
                  }
                  return this.y + '%'
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ay5mbfew/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.enabled

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.showInLegend

Comment: How to calculate X and Y coordinate under dataLabels with we have data value is dynamic

Comment: Hi @Mohit, Highcharts does not provide a functionality to calculate the `dataLabels` positions this chart type, so you have to so you must do it yourself. You can start from: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f6g1p72v/